# UBUNTU 16.04: How to set JAVA_HOME for Java?

Tags: 16.04, java, environment-variables, jdk, openjdk

I am following this 
[How to set JAVA_HOME for Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java)
in order to set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to the correct version. I have different versions of `java` in my `/usr/lib/jvm/`folder as illustrated in the following picture.

[image]

I added `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"`to the `environment` file.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
export JAVA_HOME
```

however if I run `google-refine` I have the following error:

```
./refine: 98: [: /tmp/refine.S4a2EGD: unexpected operator
Google Refine requires Java version 6 or later. If you have multiple versions of Java installed, please set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to the correct version.
```

Comment: It's so hard to read that text in the second picture, can you please edit and copy paste those three lines in your question?

Comment: @usmanayubsh I replaced the figure with the text of the file.

Comment: Please execute these commands to check: `java -version` and `printenv | grep JAVA_HOME`.  If $JAVA_HOME gives nothing, you must add new PATH definition at end of these files: `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`

Comment: @Redbob If I type `java -version` I have  `java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)` while  after  `printenv | grep JAVA_HOME ` I have `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle `

Comment: Please execute this `sudo update-alternatives --display java`. Maybe Google-refine is not understanding your Default Java, or it will work better with JDK (you are running JRE). If the result of this command above is not as expected, visit this page [to adjust your java environment](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps)

Comment: @Redbob  I have  `java - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
  link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
  link java is /usr/bin/java
  slave java.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1081
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java - priority 1081
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/man/man1/java.1.gz`

Comment: Possibly Oracle Java has no priority to Google-refine, even if JAVA_HOME is settled. [Follow these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692203/java-alternatives-change-auto-mode) to establish Oracle Java as priority to your system. In my case, I'd rather to uninstall all other and left only Oracle Java.

Comment: Side comment: That line `export JAVA_HOME` is redundant. `/etc/environment` is not a script file.

Answer (score 4):

If you installed java from ppa it sets JAVA_HOME locally in:

```
/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
```

which is added to env on user login. You can edit this file or if you use etckeeper better way is to checkout this file to any version you require.